# Add item into array without push

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to do immutable way of pushing an array into existing array but somehow my code is not working.

```
function insertItem(array, action) {
  return [
    ...array.slice(0, action.index),
    action.item,
    ...array.slice(action.index)
  ]
}

const ori_arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'james',
  age: 10
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'terrance',
  age: 20
}]

console.log(insertItem(ori_arr, {
  action: {
    index: 1,
    item: {
       id: 3,
       name: 'she',
       age: 44
    }
  }
}))
```

possibly wrong at the index part.

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, though I believe you'd want to use `action.action.index` - not `action.index` because that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup, the `{action: ... }` in the function call is too much. You just want `{index:1, item:...}`

Comment: However it is very important to note that you are performing a shallow copy, so even though you have a new array, modifying the new one may cause issues (I'm not certain how `const` affects it)

Comment: Regardless of how you fix this, I recommend against using the same variable for both your input object and for the key.

Comment: You have reinvented the wheel. The function `insertItem()` is already implemented in Javascript [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) class since its dawn. It is called [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: @axiac nope, I've said earlier I want to do the immutable way, I can't use splice.

Comment: @axiac `splice` unfortunately mutates the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the object you want to add has a nested property `action`, you might want to use `destructuring` to get just the `action` key as your `inserItem` function's argument.

```js
const insertItem = (array, { action }) => [
   ...array.slice(0, action.index),
   action.item,
   ...array.slice(action.index),
];

const ori_arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'james',
  age: 10
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'terrance',
  age: 20
}]

console.log(insertItem(ori_arr, {
  action: {
    index: 1,
    item: {
       id: 3,
       name: 'she',
       age: 44
    }
  }
}))
```

**Hovever**, if you'd prefer to avoid `destructuring`, just change the name of your second argument in the `insertItem` function for e.g. `obj` and then just add `obj` before every `action.index` in your function:

```
const insertItem = (array, obj) => [
   ...array.slice(0, obj.action.index),
   obj.action.item,
   ...array.slice(obj.action.index),
];
```

Comment: does the order matter here? how is the order works? the new item got pushed to the last item or in the middle?

Comment: @JaneEmelia Yes, it does since you are slicing the original array on `(0, 1)`, then you are inserting the new object and then adding the missing rest of the original array. If you want to add it at the end, you just need `[...array, action.item]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the parameters incorrectly:

```
console.log(insertItem(ori_arr, {
  action: {
    index: 1,
    item: {
       id: 3,
       name: 'she',
       age: 44
    }
  }
}))
```

instead pass it without the `action` object:

```
console.log(insertItem(ori_arr, {
    index: 1,
    item: {
       id: 3,
       name: 'she',
       age: 44
    }
}))
```

If you tried logging it you'd see that inside your function `insertItem` you have a param called `action`, it's value (when you call it) is

`action = { action: { index: 1, item: { id: 3, name: 'she', age: 44 }}}`

so when you try to access `action.item` it doesn't exist.

Another solution would be to change your function to

```
function insertItem(array, action) {
  return [
    ...array.slice(0, action.action.index),
    action.action.item,
    ...array.slice(action.action.index)
  ]
}
```

Comment: is there any case where slice is needed here? usually when user clicked a button to add something, either we push the new item to the start or to the end of the list, correct?